# Is there a difference between the order type of Q·ω and Q·Q?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

From what I understand, the expression is "a countable amount of the order type of Q", which intuitively should be equal to the second expression. Is this true? How do I explain this formally?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, there is a difference. Because we take a lexicographic order on two different products. One which has a discrete order and another which has a dense order.

As luck would have, however, both these products are dense everywhere and without endpoints, and the following theorem finishes the work:

> **Theorem.** (Cantor) Suppose that $(A,\leq_A)$ and $(B,\leq_B)$ are two countable dense linear orders without endpoints. Then $(A,\leq_A)$ is order isomorphic to $(B,\leq_B)$.

So while technically these are different, they are still isomorphic, so they have the same order type. That of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying: the two order types are the same.

Comment: Andres, yes, that's what I'm saying. I'm just saying that the two products *seem* different (as sets), but they have the same order type.

Comment: What about w*w and w*q? It seems like they're the same but this time Cantor's theorem won't work. What role does the fact the q's dense have here?

Comment: @Mark, $\omega\cdot\omega$ is not dense. Lexicographic product of two well-ordered sets is well-ordered.

Comment: So ω⋅ω = ω⋅Q? And Q could be replaced by any order type with a cardinality of $\aleph0$?

Comment: @Mark: No. $\omega\cdot\omega\neq\omega\cdot\Bbb Q$. One is dense and the other is not.

Comment: Is it not possible to write ω⋅Q as {$ω_1,w_2,...$}?

Comment: @Mark: It is, but this is about **order types**, not about cardinality. The enumeration destroys the lexicographic order completely.

Comment: Alright that clears things up. Thanks a lot!